# SQL Query To validate special characters but allow blank space

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In sql server, **I am validating a column where special characters should not be allowed but should allow blank space alon**e.

Here is the query I used

```
select count(full_name) 
from stg_contact_details where full_name like '%[^a-Z0-9]%' 
and full_name like '% %'
```

> For example :   full_name =  suresh krishna  (it works)
>             full_name =  suresh%krishna  (it works)
>             full_name =  suresh% krishna  (it fails to throw the count)

if any special characters exist in the column, it should throw an error. But if space alone comes it should ignore.

Please give me a clue.

Thanks
Kailash

Answer (score 0):

Since '%' has a special meaning in `LIKE` syntax, you must escape it.

For example:

```
select * from stg_contact_details 
where full_name like '%[^a-Z0-9]%' and full_name like '% %' 
and full_name not like '%@%%' escape '@'
```

This query use `@` as escape character. So first character after escape character, it will treated as regular character but first and last `%` is treated as special characters.

More: [SQL LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php), see section SQL LIKE Condition - Using Escape Characters example

Comment: what do you mean with 'special character'? and what you mean with 'throw error'?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But my requirement is it might be any special character coming in. so it should throw error  part from blank space.  Right now the problem is if both blank space and special character comes together, it is allowing  instead of showing a error message.